# Avatar image shadow

Tags: feature-request, images, gravatar

If you look at for example any user list you'll find that some avatars has shadows, others don't, here a **random example** from first page of [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users):

[image: snapshot from user page]

This is a bit inconsistent and image-shadows looks perhaps a bit [passé](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pass%C3%A9) (?), and shadows has a potential overhead when rendering the page ([a little anyways](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/css-paint-times/#toc-topic)). It also seems that gravatar images don't get a shadow, only images uploaded via the SE interface (didn't double-check though).

**Q:** Could we remove shadow on all avatar images altogether?

**Update** So it represents an elevated status (ref. [Keiwan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357545/1693593)) - it's still a poor choice as shadow is typically a *passive* graphic element. Could we have some other indicator that is more clear to what it actually means?

Comment: No free hand circles over the avatars? How are we supposed to take the proposal seriously?

Comment: All seriousness now, this seems to be about [expanded usercards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user). Are you proposing to remove shadows even when a user has an expanded usercard?

Answer (score 10):

The shadow indicates that an expanded usercard with additional profile information will show if you hover over the image. This is part of the [Established User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege that you get at 1000 rep.

From the privilege page:

> An expanded usercard is only available if there are at least 28 characters in the "About Me" section of your profile. When your profile is long enough to show an expanded usercard a drop shadow effect will be shown on your avatar.

The 28 character threshold is why the shadow doesn't show for some users, even though they have over 1k rep.